# Nginx blocks ports

Tags: nginx, debian, proxy, redirect, http-status-code-404

I'm running a debian (jessie, 64-bit) server with nginx, jira and bitbucket installed. the url is referred to as "www.example.com"

First I installed jira, opened the setup site (`http://example.com:8080`) and finished the installation.

After that I created a virtual host "jira.example.com" in /etc/nginx/sites-available and created the corresponding symlink in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name jira.example.com;   
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

this works fine. When I open `http://jira.example.com` it takes me to my jira-dashboard.

Then I installed bitbucket and openen the setup page on `http://example.com:7990` which works, too.

I then decided to create another virtual host named "bitbucket.example.com":

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name bitbucket.example.com;  
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:7990/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

but this one doesn't work whereas jira works completely fine.

When I edited the `include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;`-line in the nginx.conf to `include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.*;` it redirects every `http://example.com/*` to `http://example.com:7990` so I think I misconfigured nginx somehow.

Comment: What happens when you access `http://bitbucket.example.com`?

Comment: I get a 404 "url / not found on this server"

Comment: That's not an nginx error page.

Comment: Yeah, but if I edit the nginx.conf like described in the last paragraph it works fine. Bitbucket is running and listening on port 7990. Can confirm that with netstat and wget

Answer (score 0):

If `http://example.com:7990` doesn't work it's obviously that nginx-proxy doesn't work too. Try to `netstat -anp | grep 7990` to see if bitbucket listening connections. If not, fix bitbucket, not nginx.

Comment: Bitbucket works fine, I can access it when editing nginx.conf like described in the last paragraph and via wget on the server itself. Netstat -anp | grep 7990 returns that java (=bitbucket) is listening on this port

Comment: netstat -anp | grep 7990 returns: `tcp6     0     0   :::7990            :::*               LISTEN     26631/java`

Comment: You wrote that http://example.com:7990 returns 404. It's not normal. If you try to connect to bitbucket forward, without nginx, and it returns 404, that means butbucket misconfigured. Try to turn nginx off and load http://example.com:7990. If it return 404, it means nginx is not guilty. There's no difference between `include .../*` and `include .../*.*`, so I think this is very uncommon error.

Comment: I fixed the `example.com:7990` problem, was caused by a adding a wrong port to the firewall rules (opened port 7900 instead of 7990). -> `example.com:7990` is working now, `bitbucket.example.com` is not. Seems to me that nginx doesn't load the corresponding files in the sites-available/enabled folders. Updated the question.

Comment: For clearance, the problem is completely related to nginx: /var/logs/nginx/access.log gets every `jira.example.com` but not a single `bitbucket.example.com`. `example.com:7990` was due to misconfigured firewall

Answer (score 0):

You have a `/` at the end of `proxy_pass` statement. This means that all URIs are replaced with `/` when passed to the proxy. For example, `http://bitbucket.example.com/testing` will be proxied to `http://localhost:7990/`.

I don't know exactly how these applications use URLs, but I think they expect the complete URI.

This means you have to use `proxy_pass http://localhost:7990;` in your configuration, without the ending slash.

Comment: still getting a 
`404 Not Found

The requested URL / was not found on this server.`